# Which is the best way to say that I have substituted for someone in his work tasks?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning

I am struggling to understand the best way to say that I have done for a couple of days the work tasks of the Company owner. So far I have find these solutions:

> I have covered for the Company owner, during a few days at the exhibition
>   in New York.
>
> I have stood in for the Company owner, during a few days at the
>   exhibition in New York.
>
> I have substituted for the Company owner, during
>   a few days at the exhibition in New York.

Is there a more formal phrases I can use?

Comment: Thank @JoeBlow can you please formalize the whole phrase in an answer?

Comment: I was the authorized representative of the Company and the owners of the Company during blah blah. Being the authorized representative, I was chartered by the owners to act and decide on their behalf for the interests of the Company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

> For a period of time during the exhibition in New York, I was required to perform the tasks and duties of the
>   Company Owner

You could also append 'on their behalf' or replace 'I was required to perform' with 'I performed'

Alternatively, you can be said to have

> operated in their stead/place

Comment: Thanks but with "while" it sounds quite different because I operated in his stead during few days of an exhibition in New York.. While I was in New York sounds like I was there for something else and not for the exhibition...

Comment: @GM - please see the amended answer

Answer (score 1):

What about

> "you replaced him"

or,

> "you took over his duties."

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of @Blessed Geek, you *[represented](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/represent)* the company owner

> Be entitled or appointed to act or speak for (someone), especially in an official capacity:
>
> [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]